# Can I update bluetooth services info without pairing again?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, bluetoothctl

After pairing with a device, if I run bluetoothctl info on my device I get the list of available UUIDs on the remote:

```
root@device:~# bluetoothctl info
Device A4:6B:B6:EB:3D:08 (public)
        Alias: A4-6B-B6-EB-3D-08
        Class: 0x002a010c
        Icon: computer
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Service Discovery Serve.. (00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PANU                      (00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (c7f94713-891e-496a-a0e7-983a0946126e)
```

If I later start a new service on the remote device, this list does not update. Running bluetoothctl info will show the same cached information, and doesn't try to discover changes.

The only way I have found to update it is pairing again (notice the new serial service available):

```
root@device:~# bluetoothctl info
Device A4:6B:B6:EB:3D:08 (public)
        Alias: A4-6B-B6-EB-3D-08
        Class: 0x002a010c
        Icon: computer
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Service Discovery Serve.. (00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PANU                      (00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (c7f94713-891e-496a-a0e7-983a0946126e)
```

Is there any way to update available services on the remote without pairing? I don't want to check the pin again etc.

Answer (score 1):

BlueZ by default caches a lot of data. You can add a

```
[GATT]
Cache = no
```

in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, which means that handles used between BlueZ and your application won't be cached.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I created that file specifying no caching (only input.conf and network.conf were in /etc/bluetooth/) and rebooted, but still having the same behaviour. Not sure if it is making use of it, because I still see a cache folder under /var/lib/bluetooth/MAC/

Comment: The `-f` option of `bluetoothd` allows you to specify an alternative location for `main.conf`. Perhaps your Linux distribution stores it in a different location?

Comment: find . -name main.conf in the root folder couldn't find it anywhere, maybe one with a different name is used